# how to import js-pagination into aurelia project

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-pagination within aurelia project.

I did `au install js-pagination` and did check the aurelia.json.

That part was added to vendor-bundle:

```
      {
        "name": "js-pagination",
        "main": "dist/index.js",
        "path": "../node_modules/js-pagination",
        "resources": [
          "dist/styles.css"
        ]
      }
```

the `./node_modules/js-pagination` and `./node_modules/js-pagination/dist/index.js` are in place

I did check the vendor-bundle.js

and it has three lines about js-pagination.

One line is a source of ./dist/index.js
and next two lines are

`define("js-pagination/dist/index", [],function(){});
;define('js-pagination', ['js-pagination/dist/index'], function (main) { return main; });`

My problem is: 
I'm trying to use it inside my module, like

```
let Pagination = require('js-pagination')
```

and Pagination is still undefined

I did try with

```
import * as Pagination from 'js-pagination'
```

and `default` property of Pagination module is `undefined`

```
import {Pagination} from 'js-pagination'
```

does not make a show as well

I'm missing something, but cannot realize what exactly.
Please advice.